# identifiers srand(), rand(), and time() not recognized

Tags: c++, random, time, visual-studio-code, include-path

I'm just starting coding C++ in VSCode and am having trouble with using `rand(time(0));` in any of my C++ programs. I have been working through a textbook for C++ and this is the first program to need `#include <cstdlib>`. I think this means it's an issue with my library, but I don't know how to go about fixing it. Any help on what I did wrong would be great.

Whenever i try to use `srand();`, `rand()`, or `time()` the intellisense says `identifier 'rand' is undefined` or similar for the other two function calls.
I'm including `<cstdlib>` and `<ctime>` and `using namespace std;` in my  programs.
here's an example of my test case code saved as "rand test.cpp" in my workspace folder.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    int x = rand() % 10;
    cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to build the test program with the C/C++ Compile Run extension, the Compile & Run terminal spits out something similar to this:

```
PS C:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume> & g++ -st d=c++17 -Wall -Wextra 'c:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume\rand test.cpp' -o 'c:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume\rand test'
c:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume\rand test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
c:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume\rand test.cpp:7:11: error: too few arguments to function 'void sPS C:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume> & 'c:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume\rand test 
1`
```

my c_cpp_properties.json looks like this

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++",
            "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/mingw32",
            "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/tr1",
            "C:/MinGW/include",
            "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

for the original code I used when this problem popped up was:

```
    //checking randomness on a die
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int f, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6;
    f = 0;
    f1 = 0;
    f2 = 0;
    f3 = 0;
    f4 = 0;
    f5 = 0;
    f6 = 0;

    for (int r = 1; r <= 6000; r++)
    {
        f = rand();
        f++;
        f = f % 6;
        switch (f)
        {
        case 1:
            f1++;
            break;
        case 2:
            f2++;
            break;
        case 3:
            f3++;
            break;
        case 4:
            f4++;
            break;
        case 5:
            f5++;
            break;
        case 6:
            f6++;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "something went wrong in the roller\n";
            break;
        }
        cout << "Face" << setw(13) << "Frequency" << endl
             << "1" << setw(13) << f1 << endl
             << "2" << setw(13) << f2 << endl
             << "3" << setw(13) << f3 << endl
             << "4" << setw(13) << f4 << endl
             << "5" << setw(13) << f5 << endl
             << "6" << setw(13) << f6 << endl
             << endl;

        return 0;
    }
}
//Expected output
/*
Face    Frequency
1       '~1000'
2       '~1000'
3       '~1000'
4       '~1000'
5       '~1000'
6       '~1000'
*/
//Actual output
/*
something went wrong in the roller
Face    Frequency
1            0
2            0
3            0
4            0
5            0
6            0
*/
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try renaming your `rand test.cpp` file to something that doesnt have 'rand' in it?

Comment: Using spaces in source code names is a bad idea. Too many command line tools don't escape them properly, causing problems. Weird problems.

Comment: And please incliude the entire compiler error message. They usually tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Don't put spaces in your filenames, or in any of the folder names along the path to your project.

Comment: *error: too few arguments to function 'void sPS C:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume> & 'c:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume\rand test 
1`* is a truly bizarre error message. I'm at a loss to understand how g++ could spit it out for the given code. What happens when you attempt to execute that command line from a terminal?

Comment: after turning my computer back on this morning i'm getting different errors without changing anything. the first thing i did was to open VSC and use the compile run extension. now the test program will run and compile, with random number outputs, but the intellisense is telling me "std" is ambiguous (4,17),  identifier "srand" is undefined(8,5), identifier "time" is undefined(8,11), identifier "rand" is undefined(12,13), identifier "cout" is undefined(13,9). and is giving me similar errors on any program i've written in the last week.

Comment: I ran the die program and it no longer gives terminal errors, but still gives me the undesired output 
`PS C:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume> & g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra 'c:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume\Ch3 functions\Rand gen and testing2.cpp' -o 'c:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume\Ch3 functions\Rand gen and testing2'
PS C:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume> & 'c:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume\Ch3 functions\Rand gen and testing2'
something went wrong in the roller
Face   Frequency
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
PS C:\Users\Noah\Documents\Coding Resume>`

Comment: i tried renaming the `rand test.cpp` to  `r_test.cpp` and i still get the identifier is undefined messages under the problems tab, but after closing and reopening VSC, `using namespace std;` is no longer ambiguous and i have no idea why.